# is the converse true: in a simply connected domain every harmonic function has its conjugate

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

The question is.

Is the converse true: In a simply connected domain every harmonic function has its conjugate?

I am not able to get an example to disprove the statement.

Comment: What is the converse? Please state it explicitly.

Comment: Let $u:\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be harmonic and has conjugate, does it imply $\Omega$ is simply connected?

Comment: $\Omega$ is simply connected if every real harmonic function on $\Omega$ has a conjugate.

Comment: @miosaki This is not the converse of your statement. Instead, the converse statement should begin with "For **every** $u\colon\Omega\subset\mathbb C\to\mathbb R$ be harmonic and has conjugate......".

Comment: See [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/711950/497335)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, to the question as stated by OP in the comments. Take the real part of a holomorphic function on an annulus.

On the other hand, look at the comment by Jonas.

Comment: :-o :-o :-o :-o :-o :-o

Comment: Do you have any idea about the other converse? If every harmonic function on a domain $\Sigma$ has a conjugate then $\Sigma$ is simply connected.

Comment: @JacobSchlather I couldn't get :-o

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. If a domain is not simply connected, you can always construct a harmonic function without a harmonic conjugate there. For example, for an annulus centred at the origin, take $f(x,y)=\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ in . This cannot have a harmonic conjugate, as if it did you would get a branch of the logarithm analytic in such a domain.

You can look at a nice explanation for the construction in the general case here:

[Show $\Omega$ is simply connected if every harmonic function has a conjugate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711950/show-omega-is-simply-connected-if-every-harmonic-function-has-a-conjugate?rq=1)

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange.com! Great first post!